# Elasticsearch index creation error

Tags: lucene, indexing, elasticsearch

I try to create an Index for elasticsearch with

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex'
```

but I always got following error:

```
{"error":"IndexCreationException[[myindex] failed to create index]; nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[[enable_position_increments: false] is not supported anymore as of Lucene 4.4 as it can create broken token streams. Please fix your analysis chain or use an older compatibility version (<=4.3) but beware that it might cause unexpected behavior.]; ","status":400}
```

The creation of the Index template before was no problem, but I cannot find anything how to solve the Index creation problem in Internet. Only I found that I have to remove the stop words filter. But no documentation how to do this.

Does anybody can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an index template defined which is using the `enable_position_increments` parameter.  You can check by retrieving all index templates:

```
curl localhost:9200/_template/*?pretty
```

The `enable_position_increments` option in the `stopwords` filter is no longer supported because it produces broken token streams if disabled.

Find the template that uses this setting and update it to no longer use it.

Comment: after 6 hours the elastic search was willing to take the template again and then it works, somehow. But Today I give up to configure it, because I always does something, but nothing I want. And all functionality is document as existing but now how to handle it. And I'm not the developer in team for this part, so it hast to stay since the developer is back...